# image sizes width and height - how to view

Tags: command-line

I have a bunch of different sized images in a folder. I would like to sort the images by widthXheight in order to determine which one has the biggest width.

Comment: you can proabably get this done using a combination of `file` and `awk` or `cut`. Are you just trying to print them out in a sorted fasion to stdout?

Answer (score 3):

Try the comand `imgsize`

```
imgsize *.jpg
```

And if necessary order it by width|

```
imgsize *.jpg | sort -k2Vr
```

(`sudo apt-get install libimage-size-perl` if necessary)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the ImageMick toolbox, you can get the information with:

```
identify -format '%w %h' the_image
```

with more recent versions, this could be:

```
magick identify -format '%w %h' the_image
```

If you want just the width this is of course `-format '%w'`.

Depending on how you use the output, you may also want to add a `\n` at the end of the format string: `-format '%w\n'`.